# jQuery load() error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$('form.comment_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url : 'inc/process-form.php',
        type: 'POST',
        cache: true,
        data:({
            comment      : $form.find('input[name="comment"]').val(),
            pid          : $form.find('input[name="pid"]').val(),
            post_author  : $form.find('input[name="post_author"]').val(),
            date_comment : $form.find('input[name="date_comment"]').val()
        }),
        success : function(results) {
            $('.show-results').html(results).slideToggle().delay(2000).slideToggle();
            $form[0].reset();
            $('#all-post').load('home.php #all-post li');       
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The code above is my "jQuery+AJAX" for comment form. When I am submitting the comment form, it works fine but when I am submitting it again within a second, it reloads the page.

Comment: Do you get javascript error when you submit form at second time?

Comment: I don't get any error, what happen is the fallback php script working at the second submit. It by passed the jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You can use unbind method to stop submitting the form again.

Here is the code as a sample :

```
var $form = $('form');
$form.bind('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(){
            ...
            $form.unbind('submit').trigger('submit');
        }
    });
});
```

or you can use the it in other way 
by using $(document).on("submit", "form", function() { });

sample code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on("submit", "form", function() {
        $('#content').fadeOut(100, function () {
            $(this).html('
                <img src="//mywebsite.com/spinner.gif"/>
                <div style="display:inline;color:#1FAEFF">Loading...</div>
           ').fadeIn(100);
        });
        $.get('submit.server', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What was the exact code? and why get 'cause im using post method here

Comment: You can use $.post if you want to post the form.                                              $.post('submit.server', $(this).serialize(), function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
        });